# WCF callbacks for NetTCP binding

Tags: wcf, callback, nettcpbinding

I would like to add callbacks to my WCF service, so that
my client can receive notifications of certain server events.
I found a beginner's guide to callbacks:  http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx, but this seems to only apply to HTTP binding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't apply to a regular HTTP binding (which is one-way), only wsDualHttpBinding, which is a special binding not typically supported on platforms other than .NET. Using callbacks with NetTCP is as easy as changing

```
<endpoint address ="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="WCFCallbacks.IMessage">
```

to

```
<endpoint address ="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WCFCallbacks.IMessage">
```

and

```
<baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFCallbacks/Message/" />
</baseAddresses>
```

to

```
<baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress = "net.tcp://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFCallbacks/Message/" />
</baseAddresses>
```

Just make sure whatever port you use isn't already bound to by another process on your system, such as IIS (unless you plan to host your service inside IIS).